# PRNG output with truly random noise

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, complexity, information-theory

I am considering a situation where an adversary does not have access to the $n$-bit output string of a PRNG, but instead receives a noisy version of it, where each bit of the string is flipped with probability $p$. We assume that this noise which causes the bits to flip is truly random.

What can we say concretely about the difficulty of distinguishing this noisy PRNG output from a truly random string? Of course, for $p=0$ we recover the standard scenario for the PRNG and the problem is as hard as solving the underlying computational problem, and for $p=\frac12$ the string is truly random. But what about intermediate values of $p$? Does the distinguishing problem become significantly more difficult even if $p\ll 1$?

Comment: If the pseudorandom generator is good, then the distinguishing problem is hard to begin with, so I'm not sure what "significantly more difficult" could mean here.

Comment: Well, it becomes more difficult in an information-theoretic way. For instance, for p=0.5, the string is truly random so there is no algorithm that distinguishes from a truly random string. I am curious about this problem because it contains both computational and information-theoretic hardness to solve.

Comment: What is "information-theoretic hardness"? Statistical distance?

Comment: Hint: can you design a "PRNG" which is distinguishable with $p=0$, but isn't if $p$ tiny but nonzero?  Can you design a "PRNG" which is distinguishable with $p$ close to (but not exactly) 0.5?

Comment: Information-theoretic hardness means that even with unlimited computational power, the problem is still hard to solve.

Comment: it's not that it _must_ help, but it _can't_ hurt, if what you say is true.

Answer (score 3):

Usually what you call "information theoretic hardness" is denoted as statistical indistinguishability. And it is pretty much black and white only: Two distributions are distinguishable or not.

When you ask "how much harder", you already drift into the area of [computational indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_indistinguishability). There are plenty of ressources for that keyword, including most books about introduction into cryptography.

So the actual answer to your question would be "If the distribution of p is distinguishable (which is the case for any $p\neq1/2$), and the distribution of the PRNG is distinguishable, then your construction is distinguishable (from a truly random distribution)"

Comment: Yes, I am interested in computational indistinguishability. Any $p\neq 0$ should make the PRNG output even more difficult to computationally distinguish from a truly random string. Is there any meaningful way in which this can be quantified?

Comment: @JuanMiguelArrazola: I imagine your PRNG is producing less than one bit of entropy per bit of output, and any $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$ is similarly producing less than one bit of entropy per bit.  So then it's just a matter of figuring out how the entropy values combine.  My intuition says we just take the maximum of the two values, but I'm not really sure why.